# Nextjs config with postcss nesting doesn't work

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css, postcss

I am using nextjs with tailwindcss and i am facing the difficulty in adding postcss-nesting to my nextjs app.

Here is the configuration below for the same :

next.config.js

```
const withPlugins = require("next-compose-plugins");
module.exports = withPlugins([], {});
```

postcss.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    "postcss-import",
    "tailwindcss",
    "autoprefixer",
    "tailwindcss/nesting",
    "postcss-nested",
  ],
};
```

tailwind.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  purge: {
    enabled: true,
    content: [
      "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
      "./src/components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    ],
  },
  darkMode: false, // or 'media' or 'class'
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
};
```

In my custom css file i am trying to use it like

```
.toolbar_navigation_items {
  li {
    @apply text-3xl;
  }
}
```

then i am getting the error

```
"(2:3) Nested CSS was detected, but CSS nesting has not been configured correctly.
Please enable a CSS nesting plugin *before* Tailwind in your configuration.
```

NOTE : I also tried changing my postcss.config.js to

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    require('postcss-import'),
    require('tailwindcss/nesting'),
    require('tailwindcss'),
    require('autoprefixer'),
  ]
}
```

as mentioned in the docs but it says

```
A PostCSS Plugin was passed as a function using require(), but it must be provided as a string.
```

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue.

Comment: @sethreidnz any luck still ? i had a hard time :(

Comment: @sethreidnz you might wanna look at the answer below, works for me :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Had same error. When used:

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    require('postcss-import'),
    require('tailwindcss/nesting'),
    require('tailwindcss'),
    require('autoprefixer'),
  ]
}
```

Got this link: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/postcss-shape

It shows how new config should be written (remove the `require('package')` function wrapping the strings). New postcss.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        'postcss-import',
        'tailwindcss/nesting',
        'tailwindcss',
        'autoprefixer',
    ]
}
```

This fixed the nesting config issue for me.

Comment: I wonder were you able to add this plugin https://www.npmjs.com/package/tailwindcss-children to ur configs ? throws error :/

Comment: @RatnabhKumarRai if you're using version `3.0` then its not compatible. Also, the author of that package recommends to use https://www.npmjs.com/package/tailwind-children

Answer (score 6):

I had same issue

1. install postcss-nesting: `npm install -D postcss-nesting`
2. postcss.config.js:

```js
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    "tailwindcss/nesting": "postcss-nesting",
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
  },
};
```

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/using-with-preprocessors#nesting

Answer (score -2):

Quote:

```
npm i sharp
# or
yarn add sharp
```

https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/install-sharp